# 갖다 vs 가지다: much like 해 instead of 하?

Tags: verb, polite, polite-speech, connective-suffix, vowel

I'm a post-beginner in Korean. Before I go to the point, I guess I should summarize what I know about Korean grammar likely related to this question.

I know that, in Korean, the radical of the verbs (the root without the `다` ending) sometimes needs a "concatenation" suffix so that it can be linked to other "functional" suffixes.

The "chaining" suffix is required to form the `요` statements. I know that the "friendly" way of telling *I eat* is `먹어요` (meog-eo-yo) and not 먹다. Likewise, *I know* will be `알아요` (al-a-yo) and not just 알다 (which is both an infinitive and a plain present form, but inappropriate in most conversational contexts).

So far so good. The concatenation suffix is `어` when the last vowel of the verb root is NOT "ㅏ" or "ㅗ". Otherwise, the concatenation suffix is `아`.

These suffixes, however, may undergo contractions sometimes: two vowels "a" in a row are blended into a single one, as in `사요` (sa[-a-]yo). If a root ends in "ㅣ", that vowel blends with the chaining 어  as "ㅕ": `기다리 + 어  + 요 = 기다려요` (kidaryeo-yo).

Talking about contractions, if a root ends in "ㅡ", the concatenation suffix will depend on whether "ㅡ" is the only vowel or not (of the radical). `쓰다` (sseu-da) becomes `써요` (seo-yo), because "ㅡ" is assimilated by the required `어`, provided it's the only vowel of the verb. But if the radical has two syllables, the concatenation suffix will be determined by the vowel which preceded "ㅡ": `기쁘다` (gippeu-da) becomes `기뻐요` (gippeo-yo) because the vowel "ㅣ" requires the `어` suffix, but `모르다` (moreu-da) becomes `몰라요` (molla-yo) because "ㅗ" takes the chaining suffix `아`.

And, if a verb root ends in "ㅗ", that vowel contracts with the chaining `아` as "ㅘ": `보다` (po-da) becomes `봐요` (pwa-yo).

The only exception to the aforementioned rules seems to be the verb `하다`, which, instead of being followed by a concatenation suffix, is replaced by a "concatenation radical", `해`, used in expressions such as `해요` (statement), `했어요` (past tense), `해주세요` (request), etc.

After this long recap, then to the gist of my question: is `갖다` a contracted variant of `가지다` used in concatenations, I mean, is `갖` a transformed version of `가지다` as much as 해 is a transformed version of 하다?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commenting on what you said, a verb's present tense form is always different from the infinitive form (base form).  알다 is only the base form, and 안다 is the present tense -다 form (ㄹ-irregular conjugation turns ㄹ to ㄴ).  Likewise, 가다 becomes 간다, 때리다 때린다, 먹다 먹는다, etc.  Only for adjectives the base and the present tense -다 form are the same, as in 크다, 높다, 부끄럽다, 행복하다, etc. which are both base forms and present tense forms.

Also, 해 is a contraction of 하여 which has a connecting 여 instead of 아 or 어 (여 is used like this only for 하다, perhaps because the normal 하아 would make a muddled sound with the two syllables indistinct, or because of some other etymological reasons).

> - 하(다) + 여 -> 하여 -> 해.   (ex. 하여서 -> 해서, 하여도 -> 해도, 하였지만 -> 했지만)

갖다 is a contraction of 가지다, but the way it is contracted is quite different from the vowel contraction of 해.  가지 in 가지다 is optionally shortened to 갖 (i.e. ㅣ drops and 가 and ㅈ fuses into single syllable), but this is allowed *only when the verb ending after 가지 starts with a consonant*.

So,

> - 갖고/가지고, 갖지만/가지지만, 갖더라도/가지더라도, 갖는/가지는 - all correct.
> - *갖어, 갖어서, 갖으면, 갖을* - **incorrect**.  Should be 가져, 가져서, 가지면, 가질 based on the original 가지다.

There are several words with consonant contraction like this, such as 디디다/딛다, 서두르다/서둘다, 머무르다/머물다, etc. Contraction is not allowed if the ending starts with a vowel. because otherwise you would have confusing pairs of conjugation forms, like 디뎌 (디디(다) + -어 -> 디뎌) and 딛어 (딛(다) + -어 -> 딛어: not allowed).

Comment: You answered my question completely. 수고했어요! So, I guess I should just stick to 가지다 when in doubt. And finally I got to definitely understand the difference between the infinitive and the "plain" present form! So it all comes down to the distinction between action verbs and quality verbs (adjectives-verbs) as far as the patchim "ㄴ" or the 는 suffix are concerned.